# how to convert imagebytes to byte[] in android using ksoap?

Tags: android, ksoap

friends,

i am using ksoap library to call dotnet webservice.

i am getting following webservice reponse

```
     <imageByte>R0lGODlhlgBQAPcAAKPBqfP69Ja0m32hgxdVJdrb28zMzPr+/QRKEdPi1IGliL3PwCFXLP38+YSJhPr7+</imageByte>
<imageByte>R0lGODlhlgBQAPcAAKPBqfP69Ja0m32hgxdVJdrb28zMzPr+/QRKEdPi1IGliL3PwCFXLP38+YSJhPr7+</imageByte>
<imageByte>R0lGODlhlgBQAPcAAKPBqfP69Ja0m32hgxdVJdrb28zMzPr+/QRKEdPi1IGliL3PwCFXLP38+YSJhPr7+</imageByte>
```

removed some extra bytes from string because it was very lengthy.

1) i dont know which format it is.
2) how to convert it to byte[] to display it in android imageview.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be base64 encoding; at least it looks like the right mix of characters. The specific webservice docs should tell you more about the message format.

Assuming it is, and that one image is broken into multiple <imageByte /> tags, combine the contents into one long string. You can then use [Base64.decode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to get a byte[], and [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) to get a [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) handle, which you pass to [ImageView.setImageBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29)

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: It is indeed base64 encoding of a GIF (the R0lGOD prefix is the giveaway).

Comment: Incidentally, the base64 doesn't seem to be correct. You can test in chrome by entering the following into the address bar: `data:image/gif;base64,BASE64CHARACTERSHERE`

Comment: @Jason LeBrun: +1 for the GIF/base64 prefix comment. I think the incorrect coding is explained by the 'removed some extra bytes from string because it was very lengthy', but it could be the server.

Comment: Ahhh, I missed that little comment in the OP. That would certainly explain it. :-)